# Try to call WSAConnect (ASM x64)

Tags: assembly, winapi

I've tried different ways to call WSAConnect however all my attempts have ended in failure.

I use 0x1B01A8C0 for 192.1681.27 and 0x0340 for 16387 after using Windbg and reformed the string

My commands for build are :

```
nasm -fwin64 shell.asm
link /out:shell.exe /subsystem:console /ENTRY:main /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO shell.obj kernel32.Lib msvcrt.lib User32.Lib WS2_32.Lib
```

My console :

```
Adresse de base de kernel32.dll: 0000000000A60000
Adresse de GetProcAddress: 0000000000A73C10
Adresse de LoadLibrary: 0000000000A792C0
Adresse de base de ws2_32.dll: 0000000001420000
Adresse de WSAStartup: 000000000142EE40
0Adresse de WSASocketA: 0000000001435820
228Adresse de WSAConnect: 00000000014328D0
```

Here's my code :

```
section .data
    format1 db 'Adresse de base de kernel32.dll: %p', 10, 0
    format2 db 'Adresse de GetProcAddress: %p', 10, 0
    format3 db 'Adresse de LoadLibrary: %p', 10, 0
    format4 db 'Adresse de base de ws2_32.dll: %p', 10, 0
    format5 db 'Adresse de WSAStartup: %p', 10, 0
    format6 db 'Adresse de WSASocketA: %p', 10, 0
    format7 db 'Adresse de WSAConnect: %p', 10, 0
    fmtd db '%d', 0

section .bss
    pStru resb 0x190

section .text
    global main
    extern printf

main:
    ; Parse PEB and find kernel32
    xor rcx, rcx             ; RCX = 0
    mov rax, [gs:rcx + 0x60] ; RAX = PEB
    mov rax, [rax + 0x18]    ; RAX = PEB->Ldr
    mov rsi, [rax + 0x20]    ; RSI = PEB->Ldr.InMemOrder
    lodsq                    ; RAX = Second module
    xchg rax, rsi            ; RAX = RSI, RSI = RAX
    lodsq                    ; RAX = Third(kernel32)
    mov rbx, [rax + 0x20]    ; RBX = Base address

    ; Print the base address of kernel32.dll
    mov rcx, format1            
    mov rdx, rbx               
    call printf                

   ; Parse kernel32 PE and find GetProcAddress
   xor r8, r8                 ; Clear r8
   mov r8d, [rbx + 0x3c]      ; R8D = DOS->e_lfanew offset
   mov rdx, r8                ; RDX = DOS->e_lfanew
   add rdx, rbx               ; RDX = PE Header
   mov r8d, [rdx + 0x88]      ; R8D = Offset export table
   add r8, rbx                ; R8 = Export table
   xor rsi, rsi               ; Clear RSI
   mov esi, [r8 + 0x20]       ; RSI = Offset namestable
   add rsi, rbx               ; RSI = Names table
   xor rcx, rcx               ; RCX = 0
   mov r9, 0x41636f7250746547 ; GetProcA

Get_Function:

   inc rcx                    ; Increment the ordinal
   xor rax, rax               ; RAX = 0
   mov eax, [rsi + rcx * 4]   ; Get name offset
   add rax, rbx               ; Get function name
   cmp QWORD [rax], r9        ; GetProcA ?
   jnz Get_Function

   xor rsi, rsi               ; RSI = 0
   mov esi, [r8 + 0x24]       ; ESI = Offset ordinals
   add rsi, rbx               ; RSI = Ordinals table
   mov cx, [rsi + rcx * 2]    ; Number of function

   xor rsi, rsi               ; RSI = 0
   mov esi, [r8 + 0x1c]       ; Offset address table
   add rsi, rbx               ; ESI = Address table

   xor rdx, rdx               ; RDX = 0
   mov edx, [rsi + rcx * 4]   ; EDX = Pointer(offset)
   add rdx, rbx               ; RDX = GetProcAddress
   mov rdi, rdx               ; Save GetProcAddress in RDI

   mov rcx, format2            
   mov rdx, rdi               
   call printf                

   ; Use GetProcAddress to find the address of LoadLibrary

   mov rcx, 0x41797261          ; aryA
   push rcx                     ; Push on the stack
   mov rcx, 0x7262694c64616f4c  ; LoadLibr
   push rcx                     ; Push on stack
   mov rdx, rsp                 ; LoadLibraryA
   mov rcx, rbx                 ; kernel32.dll base address
   sub rsp, 0x30                ; Allocate stack space for function call
   call rdi                     ; Call GetProcAddress
   add rsp, 0x30                ; Cleanup allocated stack space
   add rsp, 0x10                ; Clean space for LoadLibrary string
   mov rsi, rax                 ; LoadLibrary saved in RSI

   ; Print the address of LoadLibrary

   mov rcx, format3             ; format3 is a db string you need to define in your data section. For example: format3 db 'Adresse de LoadLibrary: %p', 10, 0
   mov rdx, rsi                 ; Address of LoadLibrary
   call printf                  ; Print the address of LoadLibrary

   ; Use LoadLibrary to find the address of ws2_32.dll

   mov rcx, 0x6c6c               ; ll
   push rcx                      ; Push on the stack
   mov rcx, 0x642e32335f327377   ; d.32_2sw
   push rcx                      ; Push on stack
   mov rcx, rsp                  ; ws2_32.dll
   sub rsp, 0x20                 ; Allocate stack space for function call
   call rsi                      ; Call LoadLibraryA
   add rsp, 0x20                 ; Cleanup allocated stack space
   add rsp, 0x10                 ; Clean space for ws2_32.dll string
   mov r15, rax                  ; Base address of ws2_32.dll in R15

   ; Print the base address of ws2_32.dll

   mov rcx, format4             ; format4 is a db string you need to define in your data section. For example: format4 db 'Adresse de base de ws2_32.dll: %p', 10, 0
   mov rdx, r15                 ; Address of ws2_32.dll
   call printf                  ; Print the address of ws2_32.dll

   ; Use GetProcAddress to find the address of WSAStartup in ws2_32.dll

   mov rcx, 0x7075               ; pu
   push rcx                      ; Push on the stack
   mov rcx, 0x7472617453415357   ; tratSASW
   push rcx                      ; Push on stack
   mov rdx, rsp                  ; WSAStartup
   mov rcx, r15                  ; ws2_32.dll base address
   sub rsp, 0x30                 ; Allocate stack space for function call
   call rdi                      ; Call GetProcAddress
   add rsp, 0x30                 ; Cleanup allocated stack space
   add rsp, 0x10                 ; Clean space for WSAStartup string
   mov r14, rax                  ; Save WSAStartup in R14

   ; Print the base address of WSAStartup

   mov rcx, format5             ; format5 is a db string you need to define in your data section. For example: format5 db 'Adresse de WSAStartup: %p', 10, 0
   mov rdx, r14                 ; Address of WSAStartup
   call printf                  ; Print the address of WSAStartup

   ; Call WSAStartup

   xor rdx, rdx                 ; Clear RDX
   lea rdx, [ pStru ]           ; Pointer to our WSAData structure
   xor rcx, rcx                 ;
   mov cx, 0x202                ; Version 2.2 = 514 in decimal = 0x202 in hex, must be a word (2 bytes so only register CX is used)
   sub rsp, 0x28                ;
   call r14                     ;
   add rsp, 0x28                ;

   ; Print return value from WSAStartup (0 if no errors)

   mov rdx, rax                 ;
   mov rcx, fmtd                ;
   sub rsp, 0x20                ;
   call printf                  ;
   add rsp, 0x20                ;

   ; Use GetProcAddress to find the address of WSASocketA in ws2_32.dll

   xor rdx, rdx
   xor rcx, rcx
   mov rcx, 0x4174                  ; 'At'  original
   push rcx                         ; push on stack
   mov rcx, 0x656b636f53415357      ; 'ekcoSASW'
   push rcx                         ; push on stack
   mov rdx, rsp                     ; copy string of WSASocketA contents from stack to rdx (2nd arg for GetProcAddress)
   mov rcx, r15                     ; socket handler ws2_32.dll
   sub rsp, 0x30
   call rdi                         ; GetProcAddress(ws2_32.dll, WSASocketA)
   add rsp, 0x30                   ; Cleanup allocated stack space: standard is 32 bytes but 2 pushes = 16 more = 48 = 0x30
   mov r13, rax                    ; save ws2_32.WSASocketA to r13

   ; Print the base address of WSASocketA

   mov rcx, format6             ; format6 is a db string you need to define in your data section. For example: format6 db 'Adresse de WSASocketA: %p', 10, 0
   mov rdx, r13                 ; Address of WSASocketA
   call printf                  ; Print the address of WSASocketA

   ; Appeler WSASocketA pour cr er un socket

   mov rcx, 2                     ; Premier argument (af) doit  tre 2
   mov rdx, 1                     ; Deuxi me argument (type) doit  tre 1
   mov r8, 6                      ; Troisi me argument (protocol) doit  tre 6
   xor r9, r9                     ; Quatri me argument (lpProtocolInfo) doit  tre 0
   sub rsp, 0x38                  ; Allouer de l'espace sur la pile pour tous les arguments et l'alignement
   mov qword [rsp+0x20], 0        ; Cinqui me argument (g) doit  tre 0
   mov qword [rsp+0x28], 0        ; Sixi me argument (dwFlags) doit  tre 0
   
   call r13                       ; Appeler WSASocketA

   mov r11, rax                   ; Sauvegarder le descripteur de socket dans r11

   ; Imprimer la valeur de retour de WSASocketA (INVALID_SOCKET si une erreur s'est produite)

   mov rdx, rax                   ;
   mov rcx, fmtd                  ;
   sub rsp, 0x20                  ;
   call printf                    ;
   add rsp, 0x20                  ;

   ; Utiliser GetProcAddress pour trouver l'adresse de WSAConnect dans ws2_32.dll
    xor rdx, rdx
    xor rcx, rcx
    mov rax, 0x7463
    push rax
    mov rax, 0x656e6e6f43415357
    push rax
    mov rdx, rsp                      ; copier le contenu de la cha ne 'WSAConnect' de la pile   rdx (2 me argument pour GetProcAddress)
    mov rcx, r15                      ; gestionnaire de socket ws2_32.dll
    sub rsp, 0x30
    call rdi                          ; GetProcAddress(ws2_32.dll, WSAConnect)
    add rsp, 0x30                     ; Nettoyer l'espace de pile allou  : standard est de 32 octets mais 1 pouss e = 8 de plus = 40 = 0x28
    mov r12, rax                      ; sauvegarder ws2_32.WSAConnect   r12

    ; Imprimer l'adresse de WSAConnect
    mov rcx, format7
    mov rdx, r12
    call printf

   end:
   add rsp, 40
   ret
```

My code for calling WSAConnect :

```
    ; Créer la structure sockaddr_in
push word 0x0002             ; Famille d'adresses AF_INET (2 octets)
push dword 0x1B01A8C0        ; Adresse IP (4 octets, en format réseau)
push word 0x0340             ; Port (2 octets, en format réseau)
mov rdx, rsp                 ; RDX pointe vers la structure sockaddr_in

; Appeler WSAConnect
mov rcx, r11            ; Socket
mov r8, 0x10            ; Longueur de la structure sockaddr
xor r9, r9              ; lpCallerData est NULL
sub rsp, 0x20           ; Allouer de l'espace sur la pile pour les arguments supplémentaires
mov qword [rsp+0x10], 0 ; lpCalleeData est NULL
mov qword [rsp+0x08], 0 ; lpSQOS est NULL
mov qword [rsp+0x00], 0 ; lpGQOS est NULL
call r12                ; Appeler WSAConnect
add rsp, 0x20           ; Nettoyer l'espace de pile alloué
```

I tried to change with connect function but i give up this idea

Comment: Doesn't x64 pass parameters in [registers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170)?  I see you putting values in rcx and rdx before calling WSAConnect, but not r8, r9?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Thanks for you response, I added the code for calling WSAConnect that I used

Comment: Have you looked at the assembly listing generated by a C compiler?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes but not very helpful : 

movl $0, 24(%esp)
movl $0, 20(%esp)
movl $0, 16(%esp)
movl $0, 12(%esp)
movl $16, 8(%esp)
leal -428(%ebp), %eax
movl %eax, 4(%esp)
movl -12(%ebp), %eax
movl %eax, (%esp)
call _WSAConnect@28

Comment: That generated code is for 32bit (we know because it uses esp instead of rsp). 64bit is going to be notably different.

Comment: Also: You've never said what's going wrong?  Does WSAConnect return an error number (which one)?  Does the application crash while executing the call?  Does your cat catch on fire?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I tried with Wgetlasterror but i get an unknow error code, i get nothing on my listener, i just think it's because of error i did in my code.

Comment: So is WSAConnect returning SOCKET_ERROR?  Saying WGetLastError returns "an unknown error code" is not very informative.  More useful would be saying what error number is returned.